# Dependency preservation: Why is this decomposition dependency preserving?

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies, decomposition, database-theory

In our database class, our instructor showed this as an example of a dependency-preserving decomposition:

```
R(A, B, C) with F = { A->B, B->C } decomposed into R1(A, B) and R2(A, C)
```

In order for a decomposition to be dependency preserving, the database system must be able to check each functional dependency of the original F locally in one of the decomposed relations, without having to perform any joins.

Here, it's my understanding that the functional dependency `B->C` is lost because it cannot be checked locally in either `R1` or `R2`. But my instructor claimed that it is preserved by transitivity since `A->C`.

Could someone please clarify why that's the case?

Comment: There is a whole Stack site dedicated to Database Questions check it out: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What does "I have these FDs" mean? "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order for a decomposition to be dependency preserving, the database system must be able to check each functional dependency of the original F locally in one of the decomposed relations, without having to perform any joins.

**No**

By definition, given a schema R with a cover of functional dependencies F, a decomposition is dependency preserving if and only if the union of the projections of the dependencies F over the decomposed relations is a cover of F, where the projection of F over a subschema is constituted by all the dependencies in F+ (not in F) with attributes all contained in the subschema.

For instance, in a schema R(A, B, C) with a cover of functional dependencies F = {A → B, B → C, C → A}, with a decomposition R1(A, B) and R2(B, C), the projection of F on R1 contains {A → B, B → A}, and the projection of F on R2 contains {B → C, C → B}. This is because B → A and C → B can be derived from the other dependencies of F. In this case, when we do the union of the the projections, we obtain a set of dependencies from which also C → A can be derived (and so this decomposition preserves the dependencies).

In your example the projection of F on R1 gives {A → B}, while the projection of F on R2 gives {A → C}. Making the union of the two sets, we obtain:

```
 {A → B, A → C}
```

From this set we **cannot** derive B → C, so the decomposition does not preserve the dependencies.