# Decomposing a relation into BCNF and also about projection

Tags: relational-database

Here's the decomposing algorithm I have:

R is a relation. F is the set of FD's

1.If an FD X ->Y in F violates BCNF
2.   Compute X +.
3.   Replace R by two relations with schemas:
4.      R1 = X +
5.      R2 = R – (X + – X )
6.   Project the FD’s F onto R1 and R2
7.   Recursively decompose R1 and R2 into BCNF

I'm having trouble performing the algorithm, so I'm asking for help. I searched through SO, but the algorithm that I found did not contain the projection part. I think there's some misunderstanding about the algorithm.

Suppose I Have A Relation `R(LMNOPQRS)`, and my functional dependencies are `D = {L->NQ, MNR->O, O->M, NQ->LS, S->OPR}` and I'm trying to perform the algorithm to get this relation into BCNF.

Here is what I tried:

I found that `MNR->O` is one of the FD's that violates BCNF since it's not a superkey to the relation. So I decomposed them into two relations:

`R1 = MNRO   R2 = NQLSPRM`

now the projection is my hardest part:
I tried to find the closure set of MNRO to project the FD's, and the FDs that satisfies the relation R1 is `O->M` and `MNR->O`. MNR is the key to the relation R1, but O is not. So do I just omit the O-M relation? or should I decompose further? Did I do my projection right?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please tell us where you this algorithm--textbook name & edition. The reference will explain what the projection of FD closure F on a component is: the FDs from F+ whose attributes are in that component. The algorithm is applied recursively to each component.

Comment: The Algorithm came from my professor, but it is based on the book "A First Course in Database Systems 3ed".

Comment: What research have you done to find out what projecting a set of FDs on a component or attribute set is? Have you googled the book & seen slides at http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb.html?

Comment: yes, about projection, it is at section 3.2.8, where projecting the set of FD's from R on R1 will output the set of FD's that hold in R1.

Comment: And that doesn't say what I said in my first comment about which FDs those are? How are you stuck calculating those projected FDs? (There is a theorem you have been given relating FDs in a projection/component & those in a original/join.)

Comment: I'm very sorry but I still do not quite understand how that helps on my question. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I told you in my first comment what the FDs that hold in a projection/component are in terms of those that hold in an original.

Comment: So does that mean I should not have ```O->M``` in my projected sets of FD's?

Comment: Is it or is it not in the set I & your textbook (differently) defined? What exacty part of what exact step are you stuck on? PS I just googled 'projecting a set of FDs on a component' & got a bunch of hits including many at SO. That's the question you are asking in your post. Why didn't you?

Comment: I think it's the part on finding new FDs from projection. Follow from the definition then the two FDs I found were correct since all their components are in the new relation. Then R1 is still not BCNF since O is not a superkey on the relation. Further decomposing the relation will give me ```R1 = OM  R2 = MNR```. But no FD from the two would satisfy the relation?

Comment: What does "I have these FDs" mean? "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097) 2. What *exactly* does F need to be? Then F is what in terms of D?