# 4NF, decomposition with MVD

Tags: database, database-normalization

Let R=(A,B,C,E) be a relational schema and the set of MVDs and FDs be D={BC→→AE, A→→E, E→→ABC}.

Decompose R into 4NF.

How should  I make of this D different decompositions of R?

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Quote & use definitions, show all steps of your work following your textbook & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: "I have these FDs & MVDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the ones that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial ones that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given dependencies that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)