# Database normalization to BCNF and analyze

Tags: database-normalization

I know this is a very basic question but I could not find the answer for this specific question and so I am posting it here.

There is a relation ABCDE.
And Functional dependencies as below
ABC-D and 
CD-AE

How do I analyze this and how do I bring it to BcNF form if it isn't already in it. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook or a [SO] answer with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck. Always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)