# Database Normalisation based on functional dependency

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, database-management

What will be the decomposition for this relation in 1NF, 2NF, 3NF and BCNF

Relation -
`Transfers(destination,departs,airline,gate,name,contact,pickup)`

Functional Dependencies -

```
destination, departs, airline → gate
gate → airline
contact → name
name, departs → gate, pickup
gate, departs → destination
```

I tried to find the candidate key using closure and found it to be `(contact, departs)`.

Then based on that candidate keys I tried to decompose it into the subsequent normal forms.

2NF – No Partial Dependency

```
R1(Contact, Name)
R4(Name, Departs, Gate, Pickup, Airline)
R5(Gate, Departs, Destination)
```

3NF- No transitive dependency & BCNF

```
R1(Contact, Name)
R2(Name, Departs, Gate, Pickup)
R3(Gate, Airline)
R4(Gate, Departs, Destination)
```

Is this right or is there a problem here? Because my decomposition for 2NF does not depict the first FD.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy The post has been edited. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. PS Moreover all steps will be SO duplicates. PS "depict (a FD)" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: You haven't acted on all my comments. Most fundamentally, you haven't said those FDs form a cover & you haven't referenced a textbook or definitions or algorithms. You haven't given & justified every step. So what is an answer supposed to be?--"you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial". Etc etc. PS Please read the edit help, put 2 spaces at line end for a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dependencies are a cover, in both your decompositions the dependency:

```
airline departs destination → gate
```

is not preserved. A decomposition in which all the decomposed relations are in 3NF, and that preserves data and dependencies, is:

```
R1 (airline departs destination gate)
R2 (contact name)
R3 (departs gate name pickup)
R4 (contact departs)
```

Note that R1 is in 3NF but not in BCNF because of the dependency `gate → airline` (`gate` is not a superkey). Note, moreover, that it is known that there are cases in which a decomposition in BCNF does not preserve the dependencies.