# Higher normal form that this relation satisfies

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

Let `R{A,B,C,D,E}` be a relation with functional dependencies:

```
B->EA
EBC->D
BED->A
```

**Question:** What's the higher normal form that `R` satisfies?

**Attempt:**

- **1NF:**  satisfied, since all the attributes are defined as single-valued.
- **2NF:** I'm not exactly sure. 2NF states that there must not be partial dependecies. The candidate key is `BC`, so is `B->EA` considered a partial dependency or does it have to be one attribute on the rhs?
- **3NF:** Assuming 2NF is satisfied, then for the dependency: `B->EA`, B is not a superkey and `E,A` are not prime attributes. Thus, 3NF is not satisfied.

Why (or why not) the 2NF is satisfied?

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: "2NF states that there must not be partial dependencies. " That is not correct. W;hy do you think that? What is your (authoritative) reference? Where are you stuck applying definitions of FD, partial FD & 2NF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B -> EA
```

is equivalent to the two dependencies:

```
B -> E
B -> A
```

for the [decomposition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms#Decomposition). Since neither `E` nor `A` are prime attribute and `B` is a proper subset of a candidate key, the relation is not in 2NF.