# functional dependencies , is this correct qusion

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Consider relation R(A,B,C,D,E). The following functional dependencies are assumed to hold over R:

- A -> B, C
- B -> D

What is a key of R? If there are multiple candidate keys list all.

I think there is missing FD, but not sure can any one help and also decompose to 3NF.

Comment: What kind of notation is this?

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you show no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. Quote definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To find CKs & NFs we need FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097) PS Please read & act on the edit help re block quotations & line breaks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the two dependencies are a cover of the dependencies of R. In this case, the only candidate key is {A, E}.

A decomposition in 3NF arising from the classical synthesis algorithm is the following:

R1 (A, B, C)

R2 (B, D)

R3 (A, E)