# A non prime attribute depends on composition of a partial Partial primary key and a non prime attribute. Is the table still considered to be in 3NF

Tags: primary-key, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

Here is the table descriptions:

Students

| SID | SNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adams |
| 2 | Jones |
| 3 | Smith |
| 4 | Baker |

Teachers

| TID | TNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 60192 | Howser |
| 45869 | Langley |

Classes

| CID | CNAME |
| --- | --- |
| IS318 | Database |
| IS301 | Java |

Student info:

| SID | CID | TID | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IS318 | 60192 | A |
| 1 | IS301 | 45869 | B |
| 2 | IS318 | 60192 | A |
| 3 | IS318 | 60192 | B |
| 4 | IS301 | 45869 | A |
| 4 | IS318 | 60192 | A |

SID and CID, Composite primary key. SID,CID -> Grade and SID,TID -> Grade.

Is the table still in 3NF

Comment: Can teachers teach more than a single class? If so, seems `SID, CID, TID` needed in final table. If not, seems `TID` belongs in Classes instead.

Comment: Teachers don't teach more than a single class. Got it.

Comment: It is not clear what your reasoning is or what your question is. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Quote a definition of 3NF & the terms it uses & the terms they use etc then clearly explain why you think 3NF is or isn't met. PS What matters is what the definition says, not other things you might happen to notice. Why would they matter to evaluating the definition condition? (Rhetorical.) PS Please put everything needed to ask your question in the post body, not just the title. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer, which is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not as far as I understand it:

> A database relation (e.g. a database table) is said to meet third normal form standards if all the attributes (e.g. database columns) are functionally dependent on solely the primary key.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Since your attribute is not solely dependent on the primary key, then I think not.

Comment: That is not a correct definition of 3NF. Eg PKs don't matter, CKs do.

Comment: How so.  Perhaps you could give a better definition.