# Dependency-Preserving Decomposition

Tags: database-design, rdbms, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

> Given the schema R = (A, B, C, D, E, H, I) with the functional dependency set
> F = {A→B, C→D, CD→E, BD→AH, H→D, AC→H}:
>
> Is the decomposition of R into (A, B, C, D, I) and (B, C, E, H) dependency preserving?

I examined examples with 4-5 elements and tried to solve my example that way, but it did not work. I don't know how to proceed because the number of elements and relationships is high.

How should I approach this question mathematically?

Comment: You are asking for a textbook to be (re)written with a bespoke example. What is yours & what does it say to do & where are you 1st stuck/unsure? (And it will be a Q&A already.) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]. Dozens of (good & bad) published academic textbooks on the relational model, DBMSs, information modelling & DB design & querying are online free in pdf & html. Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks. Nor are wiki articles or web posts or videos.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: What is an "element" & what is a "relationship"? Do you mean, attribute & FD? (A FD is a constraint/condition.) Why is "mathematically" there? (What would your sentence mean without it? What would "non-mathematically" mean?)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, since the functional dependencies `H -> D` and `BD -> AH` are not preserved. A way to check this is to project the dependencies `F` over the two schemas, let's call those projections `F1` and `F2`, then see if all the dependencies of `F` can be derived from `F1+ U F2+`. In this case we can see that the two above dependencies cannot be derived.