# Normalize a table with a non-prime attribute and a multivalued dependency within the candidate key to 4NF

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I will extend [the 4NF example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form#Example) with a Cost attribute.

Define the relation from Wikipedia as `R(Restaurant, Pizza, Area)`.  By the original definition of R, there are multivalued dependencies `Restaurant ->> Pizza` and `Restaurant ->> Area` in `R`.

I have an arbitrary total function `f: Restaurant × Pizza × Area -> Cost`.

If we use our function `f` in a projection, we can define our new relationship by the projection `R' := \Pi_{ Restaurant, Pizza, Area, f(Restaurant, Pizza, Area) }(R)`.

Alternatively, we could define the same relationship by natural joining R to itself (Call one set of the columns S, and one set of the columns T).  Then, rename `(S.Restaurant, S.Pizza, S.Area) -> Cost`, renaming each tuple by our function `f`.

Or in SQL terms I would just say

```
ALTER TABLE R ADD COLUMN cost;
UPDATE R SET cost = f(restaurant, pizza, area);
```

---

In Wikipedia without Cost as a column we achieve 4NF by decomposing into two relations,

```
R1{ Restaurant, Pizza }
R2{ Restaurant, Area }
```

Why can't we decompose the R' further?  I thought that, since projecting onto  R`{ Restaurant, Pizza, Area }` yields the original Wikipedia data and constraints, that there would still be a matching multivalued dependency in my new relation.

Comment: Your "I have these dependencies" doesn't make sense. "These are all those that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial ones that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: Where are you 1st stuck, following what definitions & process, from what textbook/reference and/or with what justification? Otherwise, you are just asking for yet another presentation with a bespoke tutorial while giving no idea what you do or don't understand or misunderstand. Moreover reasoning here is fragmented & unclear.  What is "unique per entry"?--Unique over all rows? Per CK subtuple? Why say "there still needs to be a third table"? "not possible"--Why? " introduce new columns"--Normalization to higher NFs does not introduce new columns. "seems"? "overcomplicate"?

Comment: "R1, for example, still has the same nontrivial multivalued dependency `{ Restaurant } ->> { Pizza Variety }`"--Why? X->>Y implctly refers to the set of all attributes of its relation. So it makes statement about different attributes in the contexts of relations with different attribute sets.  And R & R1 have different attribute sets.

Comment: Thank you, that's it.  My problem was not realizing that adding the extra column breaks the MVD from the initial data.  So from the start, there was no MVD, only the one FD so nothing else to decompose.

Comment: A schema constrained to hold a wiki schema state extended by a Cost attribute is in 5NF. (Also 6NF.) (You can't decompose into 2 smaller projections.) (Consider the value with all combinations of the 3 original attributes and every Cost unique.) But you can show this mechanically (from a justified algorithm) because Armstrong's axioms for MVDs are complete. But you aren't following any sound process. You literally don't know what you are doing. Before you start doing things you need to find out or figure out what to do.

Comment: "there was no MVD, only the one FD" When a FD holds a certain MVD holds. (And hence a certain pair of MVDs holds.) But in the case of my schema (which may or may not be yours) that MVD is trivial. (Its associated decomposition includes a component with all attributes.)

Comment: Again: You also have to say that the only constraints are the ones implied by those ones you just gave! Because you haven't said that! You haven't excluded that there are other constraints & you can't avoid the implied ones! Per my very 1st comment! Assuming that that's what you are trying to say. And indeed why do you think that whatever ones you claim ARE the only ones? PS Yes or no questions are seldom useful & seldom asking for what the asker actually wants.

Comment: "there is a fixed list" is more (typical poor MVD presentation) unclear wording. "All Pizza Varieties are sold to all Delivery Areas."--for a given Restaurant. "given tuples ..." doesn't clearly (implicitly) quantify the c's. Presumably you want to say that the only non-trivial FDs or MVDs holding in the projection are the wiki MVDs--that its only constraint is that it's the natural join of certain of its projections. (Projecting out & existentially quantifying are analogues.) You should probably just say one of those. This all comes from a lack of clarity & justification. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Multivalued dependencies are defined with respect to a specific relation ( X ->> Y for R(X,Y,Z) iff R is the join of its projections R_1(X,Y) and R_2(X,Z) ). Extending the relation with an additional column does not imply the same multivalued dependencies remain, even if projecting onto the original three columns yields a table with the same constraints as the original Wikipedia example.

Comment: This doesn't justify all its claims & reasoning & the language is unclear. PS What does "independent of" mean? (Don't just parrot it because other poor presentations say it.) A MVD can hold even though there are other non-dependency constraints spoiling "independence". What does "the definition for" mean? And the question isn't clear about what the constraints on the new variable are.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).